# Can I call the Screen identify function from C#?

Tags: c#, windows

Windows offers a function to identify the screen numbers by writing their numbers on the screen. Can I call/trigger this function from C#?

So basically I want to trigger the same function as I do by pressing `Identify`, i.e. see the little square with the screen numbers on each screen.

Just to clarify, I do not want to find out the screen number e.g. with using `Screen` object.

[image: Identify]

Related question:

- [C# Identfiy screens number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3776752/356726)