# How can i draw to screen?

Tags: c#

I mean using paint event but not to draw on the pictureBox1.Image and not to draw to/on the image currently display in the pictureBox1 just to draw on the screen it self ?

Comment: As far as I know you can't do that, you must have some control as Canvas to draw on.

Comment: It's possible using GDI to get the Desktop Context or something along those lines, check http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/263740-draw-directly-screen it should get you started

Comment: This question covers the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536141/how-to-draw-directly-on-the-windows-desktop-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to draw out of a form's (or control's) client area.
You could make a fullscreen form (Maximized, no borders) That can have a transparent color as it's bgcolor, and just paint to it using the paint event.