# How can I play video as a wallpaper (like DreamScene) using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, desktop

How can I implement something like DreamScene using C# ?

I want to play a video in front of the wallpaper but below the icons on the desktop.

Comment: _"but **blow** the icon on the desktop."_ - huh, what?

Comment: I guess you're refering to Windows Vista's DreamScene (not dreamscreen)... Playing a video as a wallpaper, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/856020/Draw-Behind-Desktop-Icons-in-Windows) explains how to draw you windows under the desktop icons in Windows 8, and also links to an example of how to do the same in Windows 7/Vista/XP.

You have to use lots of interop and handlers and stuff, so it's not easy or clean... But can be done :P

Comment: There is no official support for drawing on the Window's desktop, win32 is the only way... (Check this one out, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536141/how-to-draw-directly-on-the-windows-desktop-c)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the media player class:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer(v=vs.110).aspx
to play a video. To hide the icon from the tool desktop, edit the property `ShowInTaskBar` of the form.

Comment: I have tried this method, but the result is not well